# splice row from array by value

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I want splice the line with value = 3**

```
[3,"John", 90909090]
```

**data.json**

```
{
"headers":[[
{"text":"Code","class":"Code"},
{"text":"Code","class":"Code"}
]],
"rows":[
[0,"Peter", 51123123],
[3,"John", 90909090],
[5,"Mary",51123123]
],
"config":[[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
"other":[[13,0]]
}
```

**I try this**:

```
var size = data.rows.length; // number of rows

var del = 3 // Value of ID to be deleted          

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {  

var id = data.rows[i][0];                  

    if(del==id){  // if del = id -> splice                                         

       data.rows.splice(i,1);

    }

}
```

**Results**:

Only splice or only loop this code works.

But, with both show this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)

It occurs in "data.rows[i][0]"

Comment: This is a good example of premature micro-optimization wasting your time. There isn't any need to use that `size` variable; just compare with `data.rows.length` directly. If you had, you wouldn't have run into this error. (You also would have kept processing further entries. Whether you want to do that depends on whether `3` could appear more than once in the array...)

Comment: Truth. \o/ Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate with [Array#forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var data = {"headers": [[{"text": "Code","class": "Code"}, {"text": "Code","class": "Code"}]],"rows": [[0, "Peter", 51123123],[3, "John", 90909090],[5, "Mary", 51123123]],"config": [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],"other": [[13, 0]]},
    del = 3; // Value of ID to be deleted

data.rows.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item[0] === del && data.rows.splice(index, 1);
});

console.log(data.rows);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**ES6**:

```
data.rows.forEach((item, index) => item[0] === del && data.rows.splice(index, 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of using a for loop, id use the array filter function:

```
data.rows = data.rows.filter(function(row){
    return row[0] !== del;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `break` to the condition, because the next element, is the one you have spliced, which is not anymore in the array.

```
if (del == id) {  // if del = id -> splice
   data.rows.splice(i, 1);
   break; // no more to search
}
```

Comment: Worth explaining **why** the error occurs (the caching of `size`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for filter your objects or arrays.  Look at the [filter method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#filter)  for your case:

```
var myObject = {
"headers":[[
{"text":"Code","class":"Code"},
{"text":"Code","class":"Code"}
]],
"rows":[
[0,"Peter", 51123123],
[3,"John", 90909090],
[5,"Mary",51123123]
],
"config":[[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
"other":[[13,0]]
};

//filter by lodash
myObject.rows =  _.filter(myObject.rows,function(row){
  return row[0] !== 3;
});
```